# Python Singly Linked Lists with Tails

Tags: python

I have a linked list that I would like to implement as a queue. I have figured out that it works but I have a question about why this specific part works. Here is the code:

```
class LinkedQueue:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, element, next):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next

    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self, e):
        newest = self._Node(e, None)
        if self.is_empty():
            self._head = newest
        else:
            self._tail._next = newest
        self._tail = newest
        self._size += 1
```

If the queue is empty and I enqueue, the first conditional in enqueue is true and is triggered and newest is assigned to self._head. But, when I add another element, the else block is triggered, and self._tail._next is assigned newest. This, apparently, changes the _next variable for _head. However, when assigning a third element, the _next variable for _head is not changed. Why is this so? Also, shouldn't _tail be changed by newest, and as such the _next variable is overridden by the newly assigned None?

The code works completely, and I understand the linked list logic, but I don't understand why this specific code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> `self._tail._next` is assigned `newest`. This, apparently, changes the
>   `_next` variable for `_head`.

Yes, because at that time `_tail` and `_head` are two names for the same object.

So of course assigning to `_tail._next` has exactly the same effect as assigning to `_head._next` would have -- how could it not, since `_tail` and `_head` refer to the very same object?

Let's see how comes that they refer to the same object!  When the `if` branch executes, you do `self._head = newest`; then inconditionally after the `if/else` you do `self._tail = newest`.  Assignment, in Python, is always **by reference** -- assignment (to a name [*]) itself never implicitly makes a copy.

(Assignment *to a slice of a list* is a very different operation, whence this pedantic parentheses -- but let's forget it for now, since you're not dealing in assignments to slices:-).

> However, when assigning a third element, the `_next` variable for `_head`
>   is not changed. Why is this so?

Because at that time it is not any more true that `_tail` and `_head` are two names for the same object: they are then names of different objects.

That's because the second time around you had assigned something different (`newest`) to `self._tail` - but had assigned nothing new to `self._head`, which therefore still refers to the previous object... which `_tail` doesn't refer to any longer.

> Also, shouldn't `_tail` be changed by `newest`, and as such the `_next`
>   variable is overridden by the newly assigned None?

`self._tail` is indeed re-bound ("changed" is a very vague term!-) to refer to the same object as `newest`, so if you printed `self._tail._next` at that time (at the very end of the `enqueue` method) you would indeed see it as `None`.  But the immediately-previous assignment to `self._tail._next` affects the `_next` attribute **of what `self._tail` referred to at that time** (**before** the `self._tail=newest`!) -- the node that with the new assignment to `self._tail` immediately becomes the penultimate one in the list.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have been using C++ and I just noticed that Python has different assignment rules (all objects are pass-by-reference). I guess this is quite convenient for certain things but confusing for others. Anyways, thank you very much for your thorough help!

For others swinging by, here is a link to help avoid my mistake as a supplement to the great response above: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this reference... http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementingaQueueinPython.html

you can use The Queue Abstract Data Type..
http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/TheQueueAbstractDataType.html